# Need assistance in Boyce Codd Normal Form

Tags: database, database-normalization, bcnf

I am stuck up in Normalization. I have normalized till 3NF. However I do not how to perform BCNF. The 3NF table list are shown below.

1. Table1 (**A**, B, C); FD: A -> B, A -> C.
2. Table2 (**D**, E); FD: D -> E.
3. Table3 (**A**, **D**, F); FD {A, D} -> F
4. Table4 (**A**, **D**, **H**, **I**, J, K); FD: {A, D, H, I} -> J.

   As mentioned in the above example, I do not know how to apply BCNF for the Table4. Attribute K does not have any dependency as per the requirements. I assume that we have to apply BCNF in Table4. Requesting you to please help with this regard. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Armstrong's Axiom:

> **Axiom of augmentation**:
>                                                                                    If X->Y, then XZ->YZ for any Z

So,this can be applied to table 4,

> IN Table 4,FD: {A, D, H, I} -> J. can be written as
>   FD: {A, D, H, I,K} -> {J,K}

Then,we can apply decomposition axiom,

> **Decomposition**:
>   If X -> YZ then  X -> Y and  X -> Z

So,applying to table4,we get,

> **FD**: {A, D, H, I,K} -> J,
>   **FD**: {A, D, H, I,K} -> K

so,the two FDs of table4 are:

> **FD**: {A, D, H, I} -> J,
>   **FD**: {A, D, H, I,K} -> {J,K}

Thus {A,D,H,I,K} is a **Super key**,by definition of [BCNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form),we get table4 is in BCNF

Hope this helps.